# Running a test in golang that only works for some versions

Tags: testing, go, version

I have a library here (https://github.com/turtlemonvh/altscanner) that includes a test comparing functionality of a custom scanner to `bufio.Scanner`.  In particular, I am comparing my approach to [the `Buffer` method](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Buffer) which [wasn't added until go1.6](https://golang.org/doc/go1.6#minor_library_changes).

My actual code works with versions of go back to 1.4, but I wanted to include this test (and I'd like to add a benchmark as well) that uses the `Buffer` function of the `bufio.Scanner` object.

How can I include these tests that use features of go1.6+ while still allowing code to run for go1.4 and 1.5?

I imagine the answer is [using a build flag](https://blog.cloudflare.com/setting-go-variables-at-compile-time/) to trigger the execution of these tests only if explicitly requested (and I do have access to the go version in my CI pipeline via [a travis environment variable](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go#Environment-Variable)).  I could also abuse [the short flag](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Short) here.

Is there a cleaner approach?

Comment: Thanks @icza - I missed that one before.

Answer (score 1):

A few minutes after posting this I remembered about [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints). Go has a built in constraint that handles this exact case, i.e. "version of go must be >= X".

Moving that test into [a separate file](https://github.com/turtlemonvh/altscanner/blob/master/altscanner_16_test.go) and adding `//+build go1.6` at the top fixed it.